# Android Single Animation Drawable Instance used in Multiple Views

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

I have an android `AnimationDrawable` which contains a large animation.(24 frame each 100x100 pixels). I want to show this animation in multiple views with different sizes, simultaneously and synchronously. I mean when view1 is showing frame1, all other views must show frame1 too, and all views are visible at the same time.

I tried creating an `AnimationDrawable`, and used it as background drawable of multiple views and used animationdrawable.start(). But after this, only one of my views animate and others stay at frame1.

I have seen these threads

[Single Animation - Multiple Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217305/single-animation-multiple-views)

and

[Apply one animation to multiple views at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841679/apply-one-animation-to-multiple-views-at-the-same-time)

but the answers all included creating multiple instances of animations. I should avoid this because loading the animation multiple times uses a lot of memory since the animation is large.

I was wondering if anyone has an idea of how is it achievable?

PS> I also tried using static bitmaps as drawables but resizing it for each view needs synchronization and increases CPU usage a lot.

I would appreciate any other method for implementing this beside using `AnimationDrawable`.

**A side question**: does android use-up memory each time we use a resource? For example if i create 20 ImageViews and set their resources to R.drawable.mydrawable, is the memory used equal to 20 * memory_used_for_decoding_mydrawable?